# Uniform Convergence Over [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis

Let $g_n (x) = nx(1-x)^n$ for $x \in [0,1] $.

We need to check the convergence of $g_n (x)$ and $\int_0^1g_n (x)dx$.

I was able to conclude that $g_n (x)$ doesn't converge uniformly , as $\sup_{x\in[0,1]} \lvert g_n (x) - 0 \rvert$ doesn't converge to $0$, where $g_n(x)\rightarrow0$ is its point-wise limit..

so from this , what can we say about the convergence of $\int_0^1g_n (x)dx$ ?

N.B.: $g_n (x)$ is a sequence of functions.

Comment: Why not compute $\int_0^1g_n (x)dx$ directly?

Comment: @EclipseSun it converges to "0" ... can we conclude anything from this ?

Comment: We can conclude, for example, that if $f_n\to f$ point-wise, and $\int f_n\to\int f$, then it is not necessary that $f_n$ converges uniformly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three ways to show that $\int_0^1g_n(x)\,dx$ converges to $0$.

1. If you know Lebesgue integration, apply the [Dominated Convergence Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem).
2. If not, you can apply [Arzelà's bounded convergence theorem](http://www.math.toronto.edu/lguth/acepabct.pdf).
3. Direct estimation. Let $1/2<a<1$. Then
   $$\begin{align}
   n\int_0^1x\,(1-x)^n\,dx&\le n\int_0^{n^{-a}}x\,dx+n\int_{n^{-a}}^1(1-x)^n\,dx\\
   &=\frac12\,n^{1-2a}+\frac{n}{n+1}(1-n^{-a})^{n+1}\\
   &\le\frac12\,n^{1-2a}+\Bigl((1-n^{-a})^{n^{a}}\Bigr)^{\tfrac{n+1}{n^{a}}}.
   \end{align}$$
   Since $2\,a>1$, $n^{1-2a}\to0$. We have that $(1-n^{-a})^{n^{a}}$ converges to $1/e<1$ and $(n+1)/n^a\to\infty$. Thus, the second term converges to $0$.